# Stop Google account being shared between apps on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, google

When I install and sign in to Google Hangouts (family won't switch to Signal) on my iPhone, Google Maps suddenly knows about it, and either signs me in automatically to the same Google account or keeps telling me I'm missing out by not signing in. So even if I don't sign in on Maps Google knows that my Google account is on the same device as the Maps app. I don't want Google to know this, but the only solution I've come up with is to uninstall all other Google apps from my phone.

Is there a way to sandbox Google apps so I can sign in to one app without the other apps knowing?

(iPhone SE 1st gen running ios 14.6)

Comment: I don't think there's anything you can do about this if you still want to use Google products.  They track your activity on their servers so the apps know when you've signed in.  The only way to prevent this, as you've indicated, is to not use their apps.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no way to do this on an iPhone without some kind of jailbreak. Google associates all their apps so there is a group sandbox into which it stores your identity / credential tokens.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW21

One solution could be to use the browser versions of some of these apps. It'd be inconvenient, but it's an option. Google could still probably guess that you're the same user (you'll have the same IP address for the apps and your browser) so there won't be many privacy benefits, but at least your apps won't sign in automatically.

The only alternative is to use non-Google apps.